# Why does \vfill not work inside minipage?

Tags: spacing, macros, minipage

Perhaps the answer is trivial, and I am facing the scenario as part of a larger macro. I faced a situation where I found that `\vfill` does not work inside `minipage` environment.

The extracted code from the bigger picture can be minimized to the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
  As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not
  certain; and as far as they are certain, they do not refer to
  reality.\vfill

  Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, but supreme
  beauty - a beauty cold and austere, like that of
  sculpture.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The `\vfill` above behaves as if it is not there.

Perhaps the design is such that `minipage`s shall remain as *mini* pages and will not fill up the whole page. But I would like to know the answer.

And while we are on the issue, is there a way I can make `\vfill` work in a situation like the above. Use of `minipage` in my macro is (almost) unavoidable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the vertical analogue of

```
\mbox{a\hfill b}
```

compare with

```
\makebox[5cm]{a\hfill b}
```

stretchable glue stretches *if needed* but has a natural length. `\vfill` is 
`\vspace{0pt plus 1fill}` so has a natural length of zero.

If you used the optional argument to specify a forced height for your minipage, the `\vfill` would stretch to fill the specified space.

```
\begin{minipage}[t][.7\textheight]{0.7\textwidth}
```

Comment: Is there any other way rather than _forcing_ the height? My argument text is of rather variable length. On a second thought I can measure the height once, then put the height in another one.

Comment: @MMA It's like a rubber band it only stretches if you stretch it. This is unrelated to minipage, it is the same on the main page (as that is a box of forced height (`\textheight`)

Comment: Why did I miss that there is an optional height argument for minipage? Thanks @DavidCarlisle