How to make "\setlength\itemsep{\fill}" take effect in beamer block environment?
I would like increase the vertical spacing between paragraphs and blocks automatically so that the content fits a frame. To do so, I use \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\makeatletter  
\let\lemma\@undefined
\let\thelemma\@undefined %<--- needed
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{frame}{A demo}

We have A.

We have B.

\begin{lemma}
Let E hold.
\begin{itemize}
\item Then F holds.
\item Then G holds.
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}

\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{block}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have H.
\item We have I.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


However, this command has effect neither on blocks nor paragraphs inside blocks. This is possibly because blocks are essentially minipages without a fixed height. Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Use a fixed space.

Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135361/why-does-vfill-not-work-inside-minipage

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Could you elaborate on your solution "use a fixed space" in an answer?

Blocks are essentially minipages which don't have a fixed height. Instead of trying make the spaces stretchable, I would suggest spaces with a fixed height:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A demo}

\begin{block}{}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have H.
\item We have I.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your recent answers.

Could you please help me with this question  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730925/how-to-increase-vertical-space-between-paragraphs-inside-block-environment?

@Akira Isn't this the exact same question again? Add \setlength{\parskip}{1cm} or whatever at the start of the blocks

Adding the command \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{} (from this answer) makes things better:

