How to increase vertical space between paragraphs inside block environment?
I have a beamer document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\makeatletter  
\let\lemma\@undefined
\let\thelemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{frame}{A demo}

We have A.

We have B.

\begin{lemma}
Let E hold.
\begin{itemize}
\item Then F holds.
\item Then G holds.
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}

\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{block}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have H.
\item We have I.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Could you explain how to increase the vertical space between paragraphs in block environment and its derivations by a prescribed percentage of the default setting?
As a result, the vertical space between Lemma 1. Let E hold. and Then F holds. and Then G holds. will increase by x percentage. The same effect holds for 1. We have H. and 2. We have I..

Adding \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}} (from this) solves the problem.

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\makeatletter  
\let\lemma\@undefined
\let\thelemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A demo}

We have A.

We have B.

\begin{lemma}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
Let E hold.
\begin{itemize}
\item Then F holds.
\item Then G holds.
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}

\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{block}{}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have H.
\item We have I.
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Can we set the increase by percentage (w.r.t. default setting) and make it globally for every block environment?

@Akira Replace 1cm by a multiple of the baselineskip or in a unit relative to the font size or whatever.
